# Make images only accessible by Googlebot-Image and block other bots via robot.txt

Tags: bots, robots.txt

Is it possible to block bots, exept Googlebot-Image, to access my website's images via robots.txt?

I thought about this code:

> User-agent: Googlebot-Image
>   Allow: /images-folder/
>
> User-agent: * 
>   Disallow: /images-folder/

But I'd like to know if this is the right way to do this before changing my robots.txt definitively. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need a newline between User-agent and Allow/Disallow like the following

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /images-folder/

User-agent: *
Disallow: /images-folder/
```

Comment: After this do you think that the code will work for sure? Do you know some ways to check it after I made the modification?

Comment: @FabioSpampinato you can use Google Webmaster Tools to verify how Google interprets your `robots.txt` file. You can never be 100% certain that a bot won't just disregard your instructions though - robots.txt is a request, not a technical restriction.